# How Can I Get This Menu Styled with CSS Like I Need It?

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation

Here is my site: http://solarsource.net/new/

Hover over the main nav to see the menu in question.

The About Us menu is almost perfect. The only thing I need to fix on this one is to extend the vertical lines all the way to the top and bottom.

On the News menu, we need to extend the vertical lines all the way to the top and bottom. In addition, the blue highlighting needs to extend the entire height/width of the box.

On the Products/Services menu, again the vertical line needs to be the entire height of the menu. Also, the blue hover background needs to extend the full width inside and the "headers" need to be bold (For Home, Business & Government, Education).

This is wordpress so I can add a special class to the menus if needed but the fixes need to be generic enough so we can add new items without causing something to break.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Via @ConnorMiles would it be possible to set the menu to display block so that it is easier to look at and work on?

Answer (score 0):

Use negative margins, and then increase the padding to compensate on the li class with the dotted line borders.

```
padding: 10px 8px;
margin: -10px 0px -10px 0px!important;
```